# why is $ u \space du = \frac{1}{2}d(u{^{2}}) $

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I'm going though a derivation of Bernoulli's Equation, and I've come across this term:

$\ u \space du = \frac{1}{2}d(u{^{2}}) $

I don't understand why the $d$ is in the right hand side of this expression. Is this some sort of derivative identity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice

$$d(u^2) = 2 u du \implies \frac{1}{2} d(u^2) = u du $$

$df$ is the differential of $f$. $df = f'(x) dx $.

Let $f(u) = u^2$. Using the definition of the differential, we have

$$ d( f(u) ) = f'(u) du $$

$$ d( u^2 ) = 2 u du $$

Now just divide by $2$.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand where your first expression comes from?

Comment: I updated. Hope it helps now.

Answer (score 1):

We know that the derivative of a given $f(u)$ w.r.t. $u$ is given as $$\frac{d}{du}(f(u))=f'(u)$$
$$d(f(u))=f'(u)du$$$$\iff f'(u)du=d(f(u))\tag 1$$

Now, the given function $$f(u)=u^2\iff f'(u)=2u$$

Substituting the corresponding values $f(u)=u^2$ & $f'(u)=2u$ in (1), we get 
$$(2u)du=d(u^2)$$ $$\color{red}{udu=\frac{1}{2}d(u^2)}$$